# Metaplectic group is the unique double covering of symplectic group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, symplectic-geometry

The proof that $Mp(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is the unique connected double cover of $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$ uses the fact that the fundamental group of the latter is infinite cyclic (the integers). I have not found any proofs of both fundamental facts about this statement:

1. The fundamental group of $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is the integers;
2. If a group has an infinite cyclic fundamental group, then it has a unique connected double cover;

Since those points are being addressed in the proof of a single proposition, I'm asking them as a single question.

Comment: 2. follows from standard covering space theory: $\Bbb Z$ has a unique subgroup of index $2$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I would appreciate a little bit more elaborating if possible. I'm retarded, I mean, a physicist.

Comment: For a nice enough space (one with a connected universal cover), there's a natural correspondence between (connected) $n$-fold covers and index $n$ subgroups of the fundamental group. See your favourite algebraic topology textbook.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I don't have a favorite algebraic topology book, so I've checked about 5 of them today to see if I could find a proof of this. The one that got closest was Fulton's book, but I found the proof [of proposition 13.23] to be too incomplete. Can you recommend me something? Also, it looks like the calculation of the fundamental group of $Sp(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is a mystery: I've only found splittings of the maximal compact subgroup of $Sp$ as $Sp(2n) \times U(2n)$ and very obscure "left to the reader" impossible proofs.

Answer (score 1):

The following statements are all proved in the books

- [1] *Symplectic Geometry and Quantum Mechanics*, by Maurice de Gosson;
- [2] *Introduction to Symplectic Topology*, by Dusa McDuff and Dietmar Salamon;

**Proposition 1:** The quotient $Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})/U(n)$ is contractible.

**Proof:** Done by constructing an explicit retraction of $Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})$ onto $U(n)$. Check Corollary 2.24 of [1].

**Proposition 2:** $\pi_1(U(n)) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

**Proof:** Uses an exact homotopy sequence and the fact that $SU(n)$ is simply connected. Check Proposition 2.23 of [2].

**Theorem 1:** $\pi_1(Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

**Proof:** By Proposition 2, $\pi_1(U(n)) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$. By Proposition 1, $U(n)$ and $Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})$ are homotopic.

**Theorem 2:** There exists and unique double cover of $Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})$.

**Proof:** $\pi_1(Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$, which is isomorphic to the group of covering transformations of $Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite cyclic and $Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})$ is connected, there is a 1-1 correspondence between subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ and subgroups of the covering transformations group. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ has a single 2-fold subgroup, so does the group of covering transformations of $Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})$. (This is a mix between @LordSharktheUnknown's comments and some proofs I found on Allen Hatcher's book *Algebraic Topology*.)